# How to get dynamic $_POST to compare it to database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mysqli, minicart

I'm creating an e-commerce website, I'm using minicart.js.

I want to include in-cart products to checkout page using PHP, how?

I tried to do it with JS and I'm not so good in it so I will need walkthrough,
I could get the values with PHP via $_POST['product_id_1'],

The problem is I want to get all in-cart products, what if there is 1000 product?

I found it could be used with IN but still i need to write $product_cart_id = '(1,2,3...1000)';
 thats not good too what if there is more??
the final idea I got is using $_POST['product_id_'.$i] with for loop,
it worked and printed all values in-cart products,
the final step is to get them from database dynamic way,
when I put `$_POST['product_id_'.$i]` in var and put in query it says syntax error,

when I change the var to `$_POST['product_id_1']` IT WORKS...

I need to make that dynamic with PHP or JS (But I will need more help in JS)

```html
// the add to cart button form
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="{$row['product_id']}">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{$row['product_title']}">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$row['product_price']}">
    <button type="submit" class="cart product-cart">
          <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

```php
// btw its the same result without the escape, fetch_array and query function all good and working TESTED
//>>> FUNCTIONS just in case <<<//

function confirm($result) {
    global $conn;
    if(!$result) {
        die("QUERY FAILED . " .mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}

function escape($string) {
    global $conn;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $string);
}

function query($sql){
    global $conn;
    $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    confirm($result);
    return $result;
}

function fetch_array($result) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

//>>> FUNCTIONS END <<<//



for ($i=1; $i <= 10000; $i++):


$product_cart_quantity = $_POST['quantity_'.$i]; // works with echo

// NOT working way but GOOD
$product_cart_id = $_POST['product_id_'.$i]; // works with echo

$result = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id =".escape($product_cart_id)."");


// working way but BAD
$product_cart_id = '(1,2,3)'; // works with database comparation but I cant write 1000 product in hands right?

$result = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id IN".escape($product_cart_id)."");

endfor;

while($row = fetch_array($result)):

    echo "<br>".$row['product_title'];

endwhile;
```

[This image show the names generated  by minicart.js on the form, AND I CAN get the output on the page with echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps0A6.png)

[and this image that i echo the product title with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF0Qb.png)

I want to to store them in var to get content from db...

```
// this is cart module in minicart.js
module.exports = Cart;

},{"./constants":11,"./product":13,"./util/currency":15,"./util/mixin":18,"./util/pubsub":19,"./util/storage":20}],10:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';


var mixin = require('./util/mixin');


var defaults = module.exports = {

    name: 'staplesbmincart',

    parent: (typeof document !== 'undefined') ? document.body : null,

    action: 'checkout.php',

    target: '',

    duration: 30,

    // template: '<%var items = cart.items();var settings = cart.settings();var hasItems = !!items.length;var priceFormat = { format: true, currency: cart.settings("currency_code") };var totalFormat = { format: true, showCode: true };%><form method="post" class="<% if (!hasItems) { %>sbmincart-empty<% } %>" action="<%= config.action %>" target="<%= config.target %>">    <button type="button" class="sbmincart-closer">&times;</button>    <ul>        <% for (var i= 0, idx = i + 1, len = items.length; i < len; i++, idx++) { %>        <li class="sbmincart-item">            <div class="sbmincart-details-name">                <a class="sbmincart-name" href="<%= items[i].get("href") %>"><%= items[i].get("googles_item") %></a>                <ul class="sbmincart-attributes">                    <% if (items[i].get("item_number")) { %>                    <li>                        <%= items[i].get("item_number") %>                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("item_number") %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% if (items[i].discount()) { %>                    <li>                        <%= config.strings.discount %> <%= items[i].discount(priceFormat) %>                        <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].discount() %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% for (var options = items[i].options(), j = 0, len2 = options.length; j < len2; j++) { %>                        <li>                            <%= options[j].key %>: <%= options[j].value %>                            <input type="hidden" name="on<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].key %>" />                            <input type="hidden" name="os<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].value %>" />                        </li>                    <% } %>                </ul>            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-quantity">                <input class="sbmincart-quantity" data-sbmincart-idx="<%= i %>" name="quantity_<%= idx %>" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value="<%= items[i].get("quantity") %>" autocomplete="off" />            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-remove">                <button type="button" class="sbmincart-remove" data-sbmincart-idx="<%= i %>">&times;</button>            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-price">                <span class="sbmincart-price"><%= items[i].total(priceFormat) %></span>            </div>            <input type="hidden" name="product_id_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("product_id") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="googles_item_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("googles_item") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].amount() %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("shipping") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping2_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("shipping2") %>" />        </li>        <% } %>    </ul>    <div class="sbmincart-footer">        <% if (hasItems) { %>            <div class="sbmincart-subtotal">                <%= config.strings.subtotal %> <%= cart.total(totalFormat) %>            </div>            <button class="sbmincart-submit" type="submit" data-sbmincart-alt="<%= config.strings.buttonAlt %>"><%- config.strings.button %></button>        <% } else { %>            <p class="sbmincart-empty-text"><%= config.strings.empty %></p>        <% } %>    </div>    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />    <% for (var key in settings) { %>        <input type="hidden" name="<%= key %>" value="<%= settings[key] %>" />    <% } %></form>',

    template: '<%var items = cart.items();var settings = cart.settings();var hasItems = !!items.length;var priceFormat = { format: true, currency: cart.settings("currency_code") };var totalFormat = { format: true, showCode: true };%><form method="post" class="<% if (!hasItems) { %>sbmincart-empty<% } %>" action="<%= config.action %>" target="<%= config.target %>">    <button type="button" class="sbmincart-closer">&times;</button>    <ul>        <% for (var i= 0, idx = i + 1, len = items.length; i < len; i++, idx++) { %>        <li class="sbmincart-item">            <div class="sbmincart-details-name">                <a class="sbmincart-name" href="<%= items[i].get("href") %>"><%= items[i].get("googles_item") %></a>                <ul class="sbmincart-attributes">                    <% if (items[i].get("item_number")) { %>                    <li>                        <%= items[i].get("item_number") %>                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("item_number") %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% if (items[i].discount()) { %>                    <li>                        <%= config.strings.discount %> <%= items[i].discount(priceFormat) %>                        <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].discount() %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% for (var options = items[i].options(), j = 0, len2 = options.length; j < len2; j++) { %>                        <li>                            <%= options[j].key %>: <%= options[j].value %>                            <input type="hidden" name="on<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].key %>" />                            <input type="hidden" name="os<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].value %>" />                        </li>                    <% } %>                </ul>            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-quantity">                <input class="sbmincart-quantity" data-sbmincart-idx="<%= i %>" name="quantity_<%= idx %>" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value="<%= items[i].get("quantity") %>" autocomplete="off" />            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-remove">                <button type="button" class="sbmincart-remove" data-sbmincart-idx="<%= i %>">&times;</button>            </div>            <div class="sbmincart-details-price">                <span class="sbmincart-price"><%= items[i].total(priceFormat) %></span>            </div>            <input type="hidden" name="product_id_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("product_id") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="googles_item_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("googles_item") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].amount() %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("shipping") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping2_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("shipping2") %>" />        </li>        <% } %>    </ul>    <div class="sbmincart-footer">        <% if (hasItems) { %>            <div class="sbmincart-subtotal">                <%= config.strings.subtotal %> <%= cart.total(totalFormat) %>            </div>            <button class="sbmincart-submit" type="submit" data-sbmincart-alt="<%= config.strings.buttonAlt %>"><%- config.strings.button %></button>        <% } else { %>            <p class="sbmincart-empty-text"><%= config.strings.empty %></p>        <% } %>    </div>    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />    <% for (var key in settings) { %>        <input type="hidden" name="<%= key %>" value="<%= settings[key] %>" />    <% } %></form>',


    styles: '',

    strings: {
        button: 'Check Out',
        subtotal: 'Subtotal:',
        discount: 'Discount:',
        empty: 'Your shopping cart is empty'
    }

};
```

I expect to make query with dynamic `$_POST['produc_id_'.$i]` based on in-cart products
// $i = products in-cart

Comment: Do you get these `$_POST['product_id_'.$i]` via form?

Comment: yes it form in add to cart button

Comment: I don't see the `name=product_id_1` in your form

Comment: I dont care about sql injection for now, stmt in final step only

Comment: Carl Binalla , I added photo for you I took write now

Comment: Does IT NOT have solution???

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you show me your scenario, what is happening there by skype or remotely. So that I can help properly.
As I am looking as per that

1) you will have to take a comma separated product_id of your product in hidden field https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps0A6.png

2) when you submit form then you will have to pass as hidden field id as like as:

select * from table where product_id in ($_POST[product_id]). Hope your Issue will be resolved.

3) Otherwise other solutions if you come with me as remote.

Comment: Thanks a lot i am facing this problem for 2 days now, how can I contact tou via skype? (if not trouble for you)

Comment: this is my skype name live:xcypherz1998